# trying to run a process from an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to run an application on the server. I have an executable file, which runs perfectly well on my own permissions through terminal services. It also runs well on my own machine through the asp.net when I run the site with my VS.

When I tried running my site on the real IIS it just hanged. I tried changing the credentials of the StartInfo to my own, and also tried Impresonate=true in the web.config to myself. In both cases it still didn't work.

I keep getting the following error (when run under my credentials and entering the server on /console)

[image]

I also have "Allow service to interact with desktop" checked in the IIS options.

Anyone here knows what I am missing? Some option I should check, or maybe some other way of doing what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new app pool with a a new admin account.  If that works remove the user from the admin group and create a new group with the necessary permissions for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run on my local IIS with copying test console app into bin directory of web site and it works:

```
        string path = "bin/test.exe";
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            pi.UseShellExecute = true;
            pi.FileName = Server.MapPath(path);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pi);
            lbl.Text = "Started Process: " + Server.MapPath(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl.Text = ex.Message + 
            "<br/><p>" + ex.StackTrace + "</p>" +
            Server.MapPath(path);
        }
```