# cscript crashes when starting a process from ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, process, wsh

I´m having a problem with my ASP application. I´m getting an error from the cscript when I run a process on the server.
When I debug locally the page just works fine and the process is executed correctly, but when I deploy the application to the IIS and run it from another machine explorer it crashes when the process starts.

I imagine it was a matter of the user, so I added this line to the web.config, to ensure that.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="password" />
```

Then, I added the user that I wanted the process to start with but the page keeps crashing. The error that I get in the server side each time the process is launch (when a button is pressed) is:

cscript.exe - Application Error

The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000142). Click on OK to terminate the application

The code that launches the process is:

```
    public static void actualizarPersona(csPersona persona)
    {

        string nombreArchivo = "card.js";

        File.WriteAllText(nombreArchivo, persona.setFileActualizarPersona(persona), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));


        Process proc = new Process();

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.FileName = "cscript.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = nombreArchivo;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UserName = "Administrator";

        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        string contraseña = "myPassword";
        foreach (char c in contraseña)
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }

        startInfo.Password = password;
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
        proc.Dispose();
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea of what may be happening?. I´ve been stuck here for a while today.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to load the user's profile

startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true

**Edit**

Try creating a new app pool with a a new admin account. If that works remove the user from the admin group and create a new group with the necessary permissions for the app.

(see [trying to run a process from an asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876504/trying-to-run-a-process-from-an-asp-net-application))

Comment: @Ok, then I suspect a general permission problem for the ASPNET account; where is the executable located, is it strongly named/signed etc. See also updated answer

Comment: I´m still getting the same error... i´m convinced that it has to be an issue with autentication and permissions... but I cant see where

Comment: @NicoRiff use Process Monitor to look for Access Denied errors.